# Seeding Laravel DB from external API

Tags: php, laravel

I'm new to Laravel. Maybe my questions are a little bit silly... Sorry...

The goal: There are some API resources and I need to take some selective data from them (It will be needed to make extra API queries from data which I already got before to get full sets of required values) and fill my DB tables with it (some as one to many, some as many to many).

The problem: What Laravel tools do I need to use to reach this goal? Is it factory, seeder or somewhat else? In addition I don't understand where I have to write the code for getting data from an external API and where (in terminal manually?) I have to initiate my DB tables filling.

Maybe someone could at least advise what to learn in the Laravel official documentation at first or some helpful reference to some article from which I will be clear how this process may be implemented in Laravel. I mean the tools' set and order to use them. Not the finished code implementation of course.

I will be grateful for any help. Thanks. Sorry for my non native English.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there are multiple ways of achieving what you want:

1. One is to [create a command](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/artisan#writing-commands) where you are going to write code to fetch this data (using curl or any similar way). And then you manually run the command when you want with whatever arguments you want.
2. Other one is to use the previous step and [schedule](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/scheduling#introduction) it to run in a desired time with desired arguments.
3. Other possible way is, if the external API can send data to a specific URL when some action occurs in that system, then you can [create a normal Route](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#basic-routing) and the API should point to this Route in your Laravel. It will be specific and only work for this API.
4. Other one is to fetch data based on an event. Let's say that, if a user register, when this is successful, you are going to fetch User info from an external API using their email (let's say you want to get a profile picture from an API and the only way to get the user picture is sending the user's email). You can do so using [Events](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/events#introduction).

There are more ways, but if you don't give too much context, then this is what I can share with you !

Comment: I see I have to learn "commands" section from docs at least.What about context.Do you mean what my app have to do? It is just representing those data from API in ordered way. API resources contain data of films' characters, films themselves, producers, etc. As for the app - it is a simple characters collection in a tabled view: for example the main page is a table of characters(characters as links to their own pages, that can be edited/updated/deleted). Besides there is a functionality of creating(and adding to my DB) a new character and sorting the data from DB in different ways.

Comment: I have read about commands and now I have not less questions than before.I don't need any connection between getting API data and some user actions in the app.I need to fill the DB manually. But I have no strategy of doing that. I suppose I have to make migrations files for all the tables I would like to have in the DB and run migrations.Then I have to make seeders for each table from DB and get in them corresponding data from API.After that I would fill my DB using seeders.I doubt it is a right way. I don's see how to use here commands except of only getting external API data.